# excel 2007 vba, delete matching folder name

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to zip through a folder and delete sub folders that match a name.  The directory has a structure like this.

```
<starting path>
<starting path>\<main folder>
<starting path>\<main folder>\<sub folder>
```

I've got the following VBA that works - up to the first match and delete.  After that point I get an error of path not found.  What i'm not sure is how to (after deleting the folder) bump it up to the starting path- or just move onto the next main folder and let it roll on through again.

```
'Looping Through Folders and Files in VBA
Public ObjFolder As Object

Public objFso As Object
Public objFldLoop As Object
Public lngCounter As Long
Public objFl As Object


'===================================================================
'A procedure to call the Function  LoopThroughEachFolder(objFolder)
'===================================================================

Sub GetFolderStructure()
'
    lngCounter = 0
    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        Set ObjFolder = objFso.GetFolder(.SelectedItems(1))
    End With
    LoopThroughEachFolder ObjFolder

End Sub
'===================================================
'Function to Loop through each Sub Folders
'===================================================

Function LoopThroughEachFolder(fldFolder As Object)
Dim P As Long

    For Each objFldLoop In fldFolder.subFolders
    lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
    P = InStr(1, objFldLoop.Path, "\TREATS")

    If P <> 0 Then
           Range("A1").Offset(lngCounter).Value = Mid(objFldLoop.Path, P, 10)
           MsgBox objFldLoop.Path
           objFso.DeleteFolder objFldLoop
    End If
        LoopThroughEachFolder objFldLoop
    Next

End Function
```

==== updated working code =====

```
'Looping Through Folders and Files in VBA
Public ObjFolder As Object

Public objFso As Object
Public objFldLoop As Object
Public lngCounter As Long
Public objFl As Object


'===================================================================
'A procedure to call the Function  LoopThroughEachFolder(objFolder)
'===================================================================

Sub GetFolderStructure()
'
    lngCounter = 0
    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        Set ObjFolder = objFso.GetFolder(.SelectedItems(1))
    End With
   LoopThroughEachFolder ObjFolder

End Sub
'===================================================
'Function to Loop through each Sub Folders
'===================================================

Function LoopThroughEachFolder(fldFolder As Object)
Dim P As Long

    For Each objFldLoop In fldFolder.subFolders

    P = InStr(1, objFldLoop.Path, "\TREATS")
    If P <> 0 Then
           objFso.DeleteFolder objFldLoop
    Else
           LoopThroughEachFolder objFldLoop
    End If

    Next

End Function
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need the additional `LoopThroughEachFolder objFldLoop` in your function, you're calling your function again before it has completed it's first loop (at the `next` command) with the variable you've just deleted

Comment: thank you for the reply.  commenting that out it doesn't do anything visual.  No other message box pops up with the next match (there are hundred or so matches) and nothing else gets deleted.  I tried commenting out the first one and it has the same effect.

Comment: If you delete a folder then what happens? The next thing you do is call `LoopThroughEachFolder` *on the folder you just deleted*. You need to put that in an `Else` block before the `End If`

Comment: thanks, that's why i mentioned needing to skip out of the current directory structure.  I cleaned up the code a bit,  i'll post the working.

Comment: pnuts - considering I don't even recall what this was for - since it's almost **15 months old** - no.